# Simple object oriented design for a patient system

Tags: java, object-oriented

I want to model this scenario in object oriented language:

- A hospital has number of patients
- A patient can have zero or more medical conditions
- A medical condition is identified by name and date

Please review my code and tell me:

1. What can I do to incorporate object oriented fundamentals like reusability and extensibility?
2. Do I need to implement an `equals` method in the `MedicalCondition` class?
3. Do I need to initialize all the instance variables in constructor?

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
class Patient
{
    private String name;
    private String streetAdress1;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String streetAdress2;
    private String zipCode; //I really dont need to preform any numerical operations.
    private List<MedicalCondition> mcList;

    public Patient(String name) //Public for constructor.
    {
        this.name = name;
        mcList = new ArrayList<MedicalCondition>();
    }  

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }


    //All setter and getters

    public void addMedicalCondition(MedicalCondition mc)
    {
        mcList.add(mc);
    }

    public void deleteMedicalCondition(MedicalCondition mc)
    {
        mcList.remove(mc);
    }

    public List<MedicalCondition> getMedicalConditions()
    {
        return mcList;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return name;
    }
 }   

class MedicalCondition
{
      private String nameOfCondition;
      Date dateOfReport;

      public MedicalCondition(String nameOfCondition,Date dateOfReport)
      {
          this.nameOfCondition = nameOfCondition;
          this.dateOfReport = dateOfReport;
      }

      public String toString()
      {
          return nameOfCondition;
      }
 }


 public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException{
        Patient p1 = new Patient("Mike");

        DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy");
        MedicalCondition mc1 = new MedicalCondition("Diabetes",format.parse("03/23/2000"));
        p1.addMedicalCondition(mc1);

        System.out.println(p1);
        for(MedicalCondition mc : p1.getMedicalConditions())
        {
            System.out.println(mc);
        }

        p1.deleteMedicalCondition(mc1); //Delete the condition

         System.out.println(p1);
        for(MedicalCondition mc : p1.getMedicalConditions())
        {
            System.out.println(mc);
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Bracing style

You started off with [Allman-style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracing_style#Allman_style) bracing approach, but switched to the Java convention for `HelloWorld` and its `main()` method. Regardless of the styles you choose, **please be consistent** on this front. :)

### Medical condition dates

Your medical conditions carry a start date, but should they also have an end date? <s>Or are we only talking about incurable medical conditions here?</s> While we're at it, Java 8 has new ['Time' APIs](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html) with a different (and better) approach to modeling chronology, so you may want to use the newer [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class.

OK, now I get it... you delete medical conditions when they are cured. If you need to preserve medical history, you now know what you can do too...

### Throwing `Exception`s

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException
```

I understand `HelloWorld` is something like a test class to see your implementation in action, but still try to avoid doing something like this, especially when it's your `main()` method. One wrong input will simply cause your test class to quit with a stacktrace. It will be better if you have a method to handle the parsing and any possible errors. For example, if you want to default to the current date in case of parsing errors:

```
private static LocalDate parse(String date) {
    // using the new time APIs
    try {
        return DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE.parse(date, LocalDate::from);
    } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
        return LocalDate.now();
    }
}
```

### `equals()` implementation

> Do I need to implement an `equals` method in the `MedicalCondition` class?

Your call. :) The longer answer is, what does it mean when a medical condition *is-equal* to another? Same condition *and* date? How helpful will such an equivalence be? To 'group' patients by the same medical conditions? If you don't have a strong case for this, you probably [wouldn't want to implement it first](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAGNI).

### Adding medical conditions

In this regard, I will recommend your existing approach over [@Amr Ayman](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/102617/27975)'s answer. This is mainly because your `Patient` class should know what it means to add a medical condition, instead of letting callers of your `Patient` instances 'figure that out'. A better refinement is to wrap the instance returned by `getMedicalConditions()` with a [`Collections.unmodifiableList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList-java.util.List-): this will prevent callers of the method to modify the list's contents directly, such as wiping them outright.

Actually, on this note, you can also consider making your `MedicalCondition` class immutable, and I shall leave that as an exercise for the healthy reader...

Comment: Thaks you , But I would like to know more about the reason for making the return list immutable. Also I am not sure why MedicalCondition can be immutable.

Comment: @mc20 list: If you return the direct reference to your medical conditions, callers are free to modify it. You don't want a healthy patient to be virtually (pun unintended) riddled with fake medical conditions, and you don't want cancer patients to suddenly walk away being magically cured by emptying their list of medical conditions. Whether a patient is diagnosed with new medical conditions, or cured, should be communicated *directly* to the patient.

Comment: @mc20 the case for immutability is related to the point above... even if you have a read-only view on a `Collection`, callers can still iterate through the entries and make changes to mutable objects of the `Collection`. Therefore, it may be feasible to do so, but if this is too arduous a task to consider for now, my recommendation at least is to let `getMedicalConditions()` return a read-only view of your underlying `List`. :)

Comment: If I do not implement equals method in MedicalCondition , I will not be able to delete the required MedicalCondition from the mcList for a patient if I provide the another object with same content. ie. if I create another object with came content of mc1. In general, how do I need to implement delete?

Comment: @mc20 in your current implementation, `MedicalCondition` carries a `Date` field, so the question to ask is, whether "Diabetes since 1st September" is the same as "Diabetes since 2nd September". Perhaps what you really need here is a `Map` of `MedicalCondition => Date` mappings, so that the `equals()` of `MedicalCondition` is simpler, and you also eliminate the problem of adding two "Diabetes" conditions with different start dates. Modeling relapses may be different though...

Answer (score 1):

## Redundant Imports

You `import java.util.Date` then `import java.util.*`, clearly the first is a redundant statement.

## Readability

This:

```
private String name;
private String streetAdress1;
private String phoneNumber;
private String streetAdress2;
private String zipCode;
```

is exactly the same as this:

```
private String name, streetAdress1, streetAdres2, phoneNumber, zipCode;
```

only the second is easier to read. This is a matter of preference, however, as it seems from the comments.

Also, why do you declare `zipCode` if you're not going to use it ? I assume that's just a draft.

## Class Design

I think you don't need `addMedicalCondition`since it's just a shorthand of saying: `getMedicalConditions().add()`. The same applies for `deleteMedicalCondition`.
Note that this is the approach used by [`javafx.scene.layout.Pane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html) and is thus the preferred approach.

If you still want to keep these methods, at least follow these guidelines:

1. Prefix `MedicalCondition` with the function's corresponding term in `List`. For example, rename `deleteMedicalCondition` to `removeMedicalCondition`, that way it'll be easier to follow when you return to it later.
2. Accept variadic arguments for convenience. In which case, add a plural *s*.

Also, you shouldn't use `String` for any kind of data.
For example:

1. Street addresses and zip codes should be in a separate class responsible for locations.
2. Phone number should be in a separate class as well responsible for communications, possibly incorporating additional functionality such as grouping of phone numbers in order of priority.

Also, why use setters if you are just going to accept all values into `name` ? In this case mark `name` public. See [purpose of getters and setters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1568230/3402827).

## Variable Naming

I suggest you improve your variable naming habits so that variables hold a representative name of what it's used for while being short enough for typing.
For example:

1. `streetAdress1` -> `mainAddress`
2. `streetAdress2` -> `otherAddress`
3. `mcList` -> `medicalConditions` (variable names should not contain their data types)

Here's an idea of what I'm talking about:

```
class Patient
{
    public String name;
    private Location location;
    // Connection should be an abstract class with subclasses such as PhoneConnection, InternetConnection, etc.
    // The list should be ordered by means of priority and availableness.
    private List<Connection> connections;
    private List<MedicalCondition> conditions;

    public Patient(String name, Location location, Condition...conditions)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.location = location;
        this.conditions =  new ArrayList<MedicalCondition>(Arrays.asList(conditions));
        this.connections =  new ArrayList<Connection>();
    }  

    public void setConnections(Connection...connections)
    {
        this.connections.addAll(Arrays.asList(connections));
    }

    public List<MedicalCondition> getMedicalConditions()
    {
        return mcList;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return name;
    }
 }
```

#### To answer your questions

1. I think encapsulation is the only needed concept in this case.
2. <s>`MedicalCondition` should be an enum because, theoretically, it only accepts a certain set of possible values. For example, diabetes, cancer, etc.</s> As you might need a specific set of `MedicalCondition`s, using an enum would be highly-inefficient and probably an overkill. A class would be the optimal solution, and by doing that, we are sacrificing the reliability of an enum for the (technical and usable) convenience of a class. To cope with that, at least add validation mechanisms for the `MedicalCondition` constructor depending on possible use cases.
3. No, only the important ones. For example, you can leave the `Connection` class to be used if asked for specifically in a method, say, `setConnections`.

Comment: I challenge that "the second is easier to read". I also challenge that a method named `removeMedicalCondition` should take a variadic argument. The corresponding method for `List` would be `removeAll`, which takes a `Collection`...

Comment: @Vogel612, I later noted that using a `String` for all these purposes is incorrect by design. About the method, it should be named `removeMedicalCoditions`.

Comment: Actually I find that advice also rather questionable, but alas....

Comment: I agree: Putting all String variables in a line doesn't make them more readable, on the contrary, imho it makes a big lump of text and harder to read. Also String is completely fine for Strings. If all you want is to store and address that you want to print, putting the fields into String is totally acceptable.What method can you think of that your ZipCode class should have additionally? The whole address can be put into an own class, of course. And I would always use getters and setters for such fields, because you can add functionality later - you cannot with public variables.

Comment: I also don't agree with enum since medical conditions tend to be very numerous and having a 10.000 line enum isn't fun at all. And of course, every condition is something specific to one individual. Maybe some criteria could be put into an enum (for example, symptoms), but the whole condition would not be a good choice for an enum. In this exact case, the fact that the date is part of the condition completely removes the possibility of an enum.

Comment: Some of the naming advice is ok, though, and personally I would also only set the name in the constructor, nobody needs constructors with dozens of parameters.

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz, `String` *is* completely fine for Strings ofcourse, but I'm saying that it shouldn't be a String in the first place. ZipCode can be, for example, an object of the CityCode class with type ZipCode, with methods to return the name of the city, to check if the code is valid, etc. Adding functionality later *isn't an excuse*, and besides, what can possibly be validated about `name` ? About your enum arguments, I think you're right.

Comment: There are some good points in this answer, but there are others that are questionable or worse.

Comment: There's enough stuff that could be validated about "name" (for example, "At least two words", "no numbers", etc.). And I think "keep your code extendable" IS a very good reason - same as with condoms: Better have one and never need it than the other way round.

Comment: Validating names: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/ Hey, at least none of us are suggesting a `firstName`, `lastName` approach... ;)