# Simple object oriented design of student system

Tags: java, object-oriented, design-patterns

I have created a simple system to get hands on experience with OOPS design and some features in Java:

**The system is:**

- A `ClassOfStudents` contains Students
- A `Student` contains a list of scores
- A `Student` can be a `PartTimeStudent` or `FullTimeStudent`
- A score is valid only if it is between 20 and 100

**I have:**

- Used enum for gender as it is a set of constants
- Created a user-defined exception to check for business rule
- Made student as abstract to make it extensible
- Used compare to reverse the natural order of sort and able to sort students

**Queries**

Please go through the code and feel free to advice all the OOPS design enhancements. I am new to OOPS and want to really understand.How to make code more extensible, reusable, secure.  Some of the questions I have encountered while coding are:

1. I don't want to create a object when score is not valid. I can achieve this by checking for score before using creating an object.  But is there any other way?
2. I am throwing an user defined exception and catching it immediately. Is it good practice? I don't want to interrupt the flow and continue.
3. I am using logging for the first time. Is it the good way to log?
4. I tired to implement as many as OOPS concepts but am unable to think of an interface. Please suggest a good use case to use an interface.
5. How can I improve the exception handling (robustness)? Is there any other way I can add the student to `studentList` in the `ClassOfStudents` whenever a new student is created?
6. Also suggest some new feature I can add to learn more OOPS/Java concepts.

I have poster another question [similar](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/102612/simple-object-oriented-design-for-a-patient-system/102635#102635) and got great response. I haven't implemented some of the feature like return immutable lists, not use throws for main here but grasped the concepts.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.logging.*;


//I am trying to write extensible calss. So I have declared Student as abstact.
//FullTimeStudent and PartTimeStudent sub classes 
//Moreover a Student need to be a FullTime are PartTime so Student object cannot be created.
//I am using protected to scoreList. It is a good way?

class ClassOfStudents
{
  private List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
  public void addStudent(Student student)
  {
    studentList.add(student);
  }

  public List<Student> getStudentList()
  {
    return studentList;
  }
}

abstract class Student implements Comparable<Student>
{
    private String name;
    private Address address;
    private Gender gender;
    protected List<Score> scoreList = new ArrayList<Score>(); //Because the subclass need to access


    Student(String name) 
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.gender = Gender.UNKNOWN;
    }  

    Student(String name, Gender gender) 
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.gender = gender;
    }  

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return name+" "+gender;
    }

    public void addScore(Score score)
    {
        scoreList.add(score);
    }

    public List<Score> getScores()
    {
        return scoreList;
    }

    // Reverse of natural order of String.
    public int compareTo(Student otherStudent)
    {
      return -1 * this.name.compareTo(otherStudent.getName());
    }

    public abstract boolean checkScores();

}

//Inheritance
class FullTimeStudent extends Student
{
    FullTimeStudent(String name)
    {
      super(name);      
    }

    FullTimeStudent(String name, Gender gender) 
    {
      super( name,  gender);
    }  
    public boolean checkScores()
    {
      for(Score score : scoreList)
      {
        if (score.getStatus() == false)
          return false;
      }  
      return true;
    } 
}

//Inheritance
class PartTimeStudent extends Student
{
    PartTimeStudent(String name)
    {
      super(name);      
    }

    PartTimeStudent(String name, Gender gender) 
    {
      super( name,  gender);
    }  

    public boolean checkScores()
    {
      int countScoreFail = 0;
      for(Score score : scoreList)
      {
        if (score.getStatus() == false)
          countScoreFail++;
      }  
      System.out.println(countScoreFail);
      if (countScoreFail >= 3)
        return false;
      else 
        return true;
    } 
}



class Address
{
    private String streetAdress1;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String zipCode;
    //Constructor, Setters and getters of Address
}

enum Gender
{
    MALE,FEMALE,OTHER,UNKNOWN;
}

// Score can be between 20 to 100. 
//Score can only be incrmented / decremented by 1.
//If Score < 40 , then status is false. Else true

//I dont want to create a object when score is not valid. I can do this by checking for score before using new. But is there any other way?
//I am throwing an user defined exception and catching it immediately, is it a good practice. I dont want to disturb the flow and continue?
//I am using logging for the first time. Is it the good way to write this?
class Score
{
    private int score;
    private boolean status = false;
    Score(int score) throws scoreException
    {
        setScore(score);
    }

    public void setScore(int score) throws scoreException
    {
        if(score < 20 || score > 100)
        {
          try{
            System.out.println("Invalid Score!!!");
            throw new scoreException();
          }
          catch(scoreException e)
          {
            Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("myLogger");
            logger.log( Level.FINE,"Hello logging");
          }
        }
        else
        {
            this.score = score;
            if(score >= 40)
                status = true;
        }
    }

    public int getScore()
    {
        return score;
    }

    public boolean getStatus()
    {
      return status;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return score+" "+status;
    }
}

class scoreException extends Exception
{
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Entered Marks are not valid";
    }
}


public class Test{

     public static void main(String []args)throws scoreException
     {
       //Polymorphism
        ClassOfStudents c1 = new ClassOfStudents();
        Student s1 = new FullTimeStudent("John");
        Student s2 = new PartTimeStudent("Nancy",Gender.FEMALE);
        c1.addStudent(s1);
        c1.addStudent(s2);

        List<Student> studentList = c1.getStudentList();
        Collections.sort(studentList);


        for(Student student : studentList)
        {
          System.out.println(student);
        }

     //*************************            

        s1.addScore(new Score(10));
        s1.addScore(new Score(50));
        s1.addScore(new Score(30));


        System.out.println("Student is "+s1);
       //Even for invalid score objects are created. I dont want them to be created.
        System.out.println("Printing content of all the scores of student");
        for(Score score : s1.getScores())
        {
            System.out.println(score);
        }

       System.out.println("Are all scores greater than 40?? ::"+s1.checkScores());

        //****************************
       System.out.println("Student is "+s2);       
        s2.addScore(new Score(10));
        s2.addScore(new Score(50));
        s2.addScore(new Score(30));        

       //Even for invalid score objects are created. I dont want them to be created.
        System.out.println("Printing content of all the scores of student");
        for(Score score : s2.getScores())
        {
            System.out.println(score);
        }

       System.out.println("Are all scores greater than 40?? ::"+s2.checkScores());
     }
}
```

Comment: Why is gender so important to students? Your `toString` method would print something like `Martin Male`. Why would my gender be important in the string representation of my `Student` object?

Comment: @MartinBean I am trying to test enum by printing the Gender.There is no particular significance.

Comment: Thumbs up on having that `enum`. And kudos for having `Gender.UNKNOWN` for a default value. However if java `enum` defaults to zero, then put `UNKNOWN` at the front of the list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [Bracing style](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/102635/27975)

You have used mostly the Allman-style bracing approach, but there are momentary lapses in your `try-catch` and the `Test` class. In fact, I will also suggest introducing braces for the `if`-statements. Regardless of the styles you choose, please be consistent on this front. :)

## Constructor chaining

```
Student(String name) 
{
    this.name = name;
    this.gender = Gender.UNKNOWN;
}  

Student(String name, Gender gender) 
{
    this.name = name;
    this.gender = gender;
}
```

One of these two constructors should be chained to the other, which will facilitate in making your fields `final` as well:

```
class Student
{

    private final String name;
    private final Gender gender;

    Student(String name) 
    {
        this(name, Gender.UNKNOWN);
    }  

    Student(String name, Gender gender) 
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    // ...
}
```

## Reverse comparisons

If you happen to be on Java 8, you can make use of [`Comparator.reverseOrder()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#reverseOrder--) to do this for you:

```
private static final Comparator<String> REVERSE_COMPARATOR = Comparator.reverseOrder();

public int compareTo(Student otherStudent)
{
    // return -1 * this.name.compareTo(otherStudent.getName());
    return REVERSE_COMPARATOR.compare(name, otherStudent.name);
}
```

## Can a full-time students become part-time, and vice versa?

Your current implementations for `FullTime` and `PartTime` students are fine, but you may also want to consider the relationships between the types of students, the common fields/methods/properties of students, and how the scores are 'checked'. An alternative solution is to instead consider full-timers or part-timers as only a *status* to any `Student`, similar to what you are doing for gender now:

```
// switching to Java bracing convention for illustration
enum StudentType {
    FULL_TIME {
        @Override
        public boolean checkScores(Student student) { ... }
    },
    PART_TIME {
        @Override
        public boolean checkScores(Student student) { ... }
    };

    public abstract boolean checkScores(Student student);
}
```

In this case, a `Student` (which is now non-abstract) can be toggled between full-time and part-time status, and arguably any `Collection` of students can be easily filtered by checking `student.getType() == StudentType.FULL_TIME`, instead of `FullTimeStudent.class.isInstance(student)`. Of course, if you start to have more specific methods for each type of students, then the inheritance way will then become a better modeling approach.

## What's in a `Score`?

As it stands, I'm not too sure about the usefulness of your `Score` class. It is nothing but a wrapper over an `int` now, and even the `boolean status` can be easily derived from the score. In any case, [MAG](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/105153/27975)'s answer offers some suitable enhancements to the class, so I'll suggest taking a look at that.

> ```
> //I am throwing an user defined exception and catching it immediately, 
> //is it a good practice. I dont want to disturb the flow and continue?
> //I am using logging for the first time. Is it the good way to write this?
> ```

*Throwing a specific `Exception` and catching that* does seem... a little odd. It is as-if you are trying to control execution flow... Anyways, `ScoreException` (note: `PascalCase` for the class name) also seems to be a redundant class, as the built-in `IllegalArgumentException` ought to be good enough to convey the same exception cause.

As for logging, you may want to take a look at logging *frameworks* such as [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org) to handle logging in your codebase. On a related note, this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11359187/why-not-use-java-util-logging) provides some useful insight regarding for-and-against the `java.util.logging.*` classes that you have adopted.

Comment: `FullTimeStudent.class.isInstance(student)` is shorter as `student instanceof FullTimeStudent` :D

Comment: @Vogel612 was comparing using ways where the 'type' can be programatically derived, e.g. `boolean isType(Student student, ??? full/part-time)`. ;)

Comment: Exceptions as validation handling is not so odd as it is flat wrong. However when throwing exceptions - for the right reasons of course -  catching is pointless if we are not adding contextual information that helps understand/debug the exception. Having done that, rethrow it. Further in catching specific exception types, we know what particular information would be helpful in understanding that specific kind. And we can customize further handling of it if desired.

Answer (score 5):

You should make your Score class immutable. That way you just need to enforce invariants in the constructor. For more information on immutability you should read Item 15: Minimize Mutability from the book Effective Java by Joshua Bloch. Also your constructor is package private so Score can only be created inside the same package in which it is define. There are other classes that would benefit from immutability (for example Address).

This would be my version on Score :

```
public final class Score
{

    private final static int  THRESHOLD =40;

    private final int score;
    // There is no point on catching an exception after throwing it
    Score(int score)
    {
        if(score < 20 || score > 100)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid score");

        //Always initialize non-static members in the constructor
        this.score= score;      
    }

    public Score changeScore(int score)
    {
        return new Score(score);
    }

    public int getScore()
    {
        return score;
    }

    // There is no point in having a boolean member 
    public boolean getStatus()
    {
      return score >= THRESHOLD;
    }

    //Always use override
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return score+" "+getStatus();
    }
}
```

Also never do this:

```
if (countScoreFail >= 3)
        return false;
      else 
        return true;
```

This always can be condense to single boolean expression:

```
return countScoreFail < 3;
```

Finally I would also recommend you to use more interfaces to minimize coupling. (Look up SOLID principles).

Comment: @MAG Could you suggest where can use Interfaces in this design.

Comment: I think `score` should be "validating" the score, not throwing an exception. Exceptions should be reserved for things one generally cannot recover from. Nonetheless, validate or exceptional-ized how about capturing that score value?